# Can one person adopt Agile techniques?

Tags: agile

Looking for work at the moment, I'm seeing a lot of places asking for Agile experience, but until I get a job with a team that is using Agile, I suspect I'll never get the experience.

Is it possible to adopt Agile methodologies with just one person?

Sort of answering my own question, there's similar questions at :-

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407189/can-agile-scrum-be-used-by-1-or-2-developers

(I guess I should get better at searching.)

Comment: There's no point doing agile for one person. The purpose for agile is to radiate communication.

Comment: @jpartogi I don't not agree with your first claim nor with your understanding of Agile. Both points are just not true.

Comment: Are the job posts placeing agile under requirements or preferences?  Maybe you need to show a willingness to use agile and demonstrate some self-study on the subject.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because project management is off-topic at SO.

Comment: The purpose of doing agile for one person is to prove that you have working knowledge of it, if such is required for the overwhelming majority of job applications. In Feb 2018, I am in the same position as the OP was in Feb 2010.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to be coming at this from a work experience point of view; if you are looking to build relevant experience to get you a job on an agile project I would probably think a little more laterally.

Firstly could you work with others, maybe on an open source project? That would be a good opportunity to try out agile methods with others who may have more experience.

Secondly, you could look at using some of the common techniques or tools, even if it's just to learn how the tools work - e.g. you could set up a continues integration server to run builds and unit tests when you check in code. If you are working on your own you won't gain much in terms of productivity by doing this but you would gain some skills and have something relevant to say to future employers which would indicate you are committed to the agile style.

Comment: I'm gonna mark this one as accepted, since you pick up on the work experience aspect and provide practical advice on how to demonstrate it to potential employers

Comment: While open source might be one way to get experience, due to its distributed nature and rarely meeting people face-to-face, I don't know how effective it would be vs commercial experience of from working in an office where it's easier to collaborate and share ideas with colleagues.

Comment: @greg Sure. Things liek scrum or pair-programming aren't going to work, but other aspects might e.g.  no reason not to do TDD or CI. Not sure if they are strictly under the definition of "agile" but I think there is useful experience to be had there.

Answer (score 11):

Yes

Check out PXP or Personal Extreme Programming.

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1593127

Summary from the paper:

> Personal Extreme Programming (PXP) is
>   a software  development process for a
>   single person team. It is based on the
>   values of Extreme Programming (XP)
>   i.e. simplicity,  communication,
>   feedback, and courage. It works by
>   keeping the  important aspects of XP
>   and refining the values so that they
>   can  fit in a lone programmer
>   situation.  PXP can still be refined
>   and improved. It is in the tradition
>   of  XP practitioners to vary XP to
>   encompass whatever works. We  hope
>   that PXP inherits these pragmatic
>   roots, as well. ***Giving up  XP tenets
>   like pair programming is not
>   necessarily a tragedy***.  We still
>   believe that following XP strictly is
>   a more effective  way to pursue
>   multi-person projects. But we are also
>   convinced  that many of the XP
>   practices and methods can be applied
>   to  individual work.     The PXP
>   approach tries to balance between the
>   "too heavy" and  the "too light"
>   methodologies. PXP will inject the
>   right amount  of rigor for the
>   situation without overburdening the
>   team with  unnecessary bureaucracy.

Comment: If you can't see the paper. Try Googling the term. Pair programming is natrually void, but everythig else works. I'm using it on a project now.

Comment: Interesting concept - is there a way to actually see the paper without  having an ACM member login though?

Comment: The comparison table is much bigger than I remembered, so instead I'll post the summary.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - it is possible to do many agile *practices* as an individual.

**If you already know how to do these, you can do them as a sole developer:**

- test-driven development - great place to start
- refactoring
- continuous integration
- doing the simplest thing that could possibly work (and evolving it through refactoring)
- automated deployment
- planning meetings (a team of one plus customer)

**Things you can't do on your own:**

- pair programming
- CRC/RRC workshops (... you'd have to talk to yourself quite a lot)

Answer (score 4):

Pair programming would be hard this way :)

Let's check [Agile Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development#Principles):

- **Individuals and interactions** over processes and tools
- **Working software** over comprehensive documentation
- **Customer collaboration** over contract negotiation
- **Responding to change** over following a plan

You can do all of those things even while working on some personal project alone. You can use also [GTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) while working alone, you can develop your product through iterations, you can adopt [timeboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeboxing), you can ask some family members or friends to do usability tests with you (and this works really well).

As a conclusion, you can really get tons of Agile experiences alone. I strongly recommend you to read some books first tho, as some of principles can be easily misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

Some aspects can be done alone: running a product backlog and using a task board come to mind. See what the [secretGeek](http://secretgeek.net/desk_story_wall.asp) is doing.

Of course some cannot: pair programming, scrums etc...

Comment: Nice - I can put my home office whiteboard to good use rather than using the piece of A3 he suggests though.

Comment: +1 for the link if I had votes left... :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently interrupted a big project. It was a medical software project. While working on it, I realized some patterns about solo programming. I want to share my experiences here:

1. Your software's working logic must always reflect the real world. You catch fish with fishing rod, not baseball bat; so forget it.
2. Always start building from the project element to which all other elements refer. That makes sense if you think that like the function in a software project which is called at most. That might be database modeling. It would be useless if you model data access layer first, before modeling database.
3. Never mind changing variable names. That's the most written entry in a programmer's diary; so no need to be ashamed.
4. Methodology changes the world. Make worth of it. Make every single logical process with a function or procedure. When project gets huge you will understand thats the best way.
5. If you're not designing a language compiler in assembly do not hesitate using huge procedure call chains in which one calls another and that calls another and so on. Use methods everywhere, nearly resemble every single entity with classes and be modular.
6. Modularity is everything. Set modularity your primary goal. Have i said it is everything meanwhile?
7. Last word for beginning the project. If you're building an apartment you install main entrance at last. But when using, you enter the building from entrance. Be aware.

These are some of my design principles I learned and learning day by day. I hope having been useful. Do your best.

Comment: Some of your points are anti-agile and/or even atipatterns. Namely 2, 4, 7. We sould start from UI and mock real data. One logical/user operation mostly becomes a large set of methods, not a single one. In Agile, you should start to create from the element that is a starting one for a user.

Answer (score 2):

While some Agile practices are directly targeted at more than one person teams, they are just **practices**, they are just a mean, not an end. I mean, Agile is **not** about doing pair programming, stand up meetings, etc. Agile is about **maximizing the customer value** while minimizing waste **to provide the most optimal ROI**. Agile is business oriented, practices are just a way to achieve this goal in a given context. So, back to the initial question, it's definitely possible to adopt Agile practices (that make sense in your context) to maximize the delivered value: continuous planning, limiting Work In Progress, Stop-the-Line culture, time boxing, high quality, just enough specifications, just enough and just in time documentation, etc, etc.

Comment: +1 Everyone seems to be focusing on Pair Programming, but as you point out this isn't the be all and end all to Agile - indeed, the main argument for PP seemed to be to to aid knowledge sharing where it is hampered by a lack of documentation elsewhere.

Comment: Pair programming comes more from XP (which is more prescriptive) than Agile/Scrum.

Comment: Agile!=Scrum, Agile is just an umbrella term for many methods, Scrum and XP being some of them. And while Pair Programming is one of the XP practices (which captures many practices **as an indivisible set**), XP doesn't have the exclusivity of Pair Programming, you can use it outside of XP.

Answer (score 1):

Definately. Agile is very flexible in terms of how many people are involved. Some methodologies, like Scrum, focus mostly on doing as much as possible in a limited time, like two weeks (sprints). That includes whatever you want it to. If your team requires QA, then that is part of it. As a loner, you decide what you want to include.

After the scrum sprint, you look at what you could have done differently to get more done, and move to the next one.

Some other methodologies focus more on getting features done in each iteration, say three small features developed, tested and refactored.

As you can see, there are tons of ways to apply agile to any project. You decide which aspects you want. Though obviously one integral part is doing things in small increments.

Comment: I guess this leads to a subsequent question then - How do I prove to a prospective employer I adopt such practices when I'm doing it solo?

Comment: Explain how your system works and how it helped you accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

XP/TDD scales from one to one thousand. Pair programming is optional.

Answer (score 0):

YES.

Agile is more of a state of mind than just a  methodology of software development like waterfall.
Scrum is one of the very popular agile methodologies. You can study below aspects of scrum in detail:

1. Benefits of Scrum/Agile over Waterfall
2. How can you create better "products" with Scrum/Agile
3. What are the types of projects better suited for Scrum
4. Pros and Cons of Scrum
5. Scrum Rituals and why are they necessary (What advantage do they
   bring)
6. Different roles in scrums and their responsibilities (Scrum Master,
   Product Owner and Development Team)

After you have good understanding of working of scrum and its benefits, try to create a pet project. 
You will have to play all the roles yourself. You can try to distinguish between what role you are playing currently by wearing different colored hats for each role.

Example:

**Product owner :** Think from product perspective, what should be the features in the product and why would they be important for your users etc. Then proceed with all the scrum practices.

**Scrum Master:** Keep checking if you are following all scrum rituals in the right sense and spirit and are you able to derive benefits out of it.

There will be limitations,example you cannot have Daily stand-up meeting, obviously because you are the only person in the project. But if you follow above, you should be good to secure a job and play your part well in the team.